# Find an integer such that linear equation becomes divisible by another given integer

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, asymptotics

Given integers a, b, and c all <=n, is there an efficient algorithm to find an integer y
such that a | c + b*y? One brute force approach will be to check for all y = 0 to n 
and if there is a solution, there must be a solution within this range. 
That will be O(n)

Comment: Note that this is a linear congruence. You have to solve $by\equiv -c (\text{mod } a)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  You are asking how to solve a linear congruence $by \equiv -c \pmod a$.  The solution is to compute the [modular inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) of $b$ modulo $a$ using the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm), multiply both sides of the equation by that modular inverse, and then read off the solution.  This can be done in $O(\log^2 n)$ time.